# multiprocessing a function with *args i

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, subprocess

can someone help me to run the function *foo()* in parallel instead of using a for loop as described below?

```
def foo(a,b,c):
    print(a+ " | Process: {}".format(b))
    d = b*c
    print("test multiplication: {}".format(d))
    print('')

a = "Hello World"
c = 2

for i in range(5):    
    b = 1 + i  
    args = [a,b,c]    
    foo(*args)
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html? Or https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html?

Answer (score 0):

In order to call several functions in parallel you must use threads, you can use one for every function that you need to use in parallel.
you can read more about threads in general [here](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)

```py
import threading
def foo(a,b,c):
    print(a+ " | Process: {}".format(b))
    d = b*c
    print("test multiplication: {}".format(d))
    print('')
x = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=(1,2,3))
x.start()
```

Create threads, or use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module in order to create a workers pool.

Comment: This code does not run 5 functions in parallel, which is what was asked. It just runs one of them in a separate thread.

Comment: If you want to run 5 functions in parallel, use a different thread for each one, this is just an example as to how to use threading.
You need to implement this in your own code and modify it to your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Thread` initializing the `target` and `args` parameters with the function to run and its arguments.  Call `.start()` to get it running and `.join()` to wait for it to complete:

```
from threading import Thread

def foo(a,b,c):
    print(a+ " | Process: {}".format(b))
    d = b*c
    print("test multiplication: {}".format(d))
    print('')

threads = [Thread(target=foo,args=('Hello World',i+1,2)) for i in range(5)]

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Output:

```
Hello World | Process: 1
test multiplication: 2

Hello World | Process: 2
test multiplication: 4
Hello World | Process: 3

test multiplication: 6
Hello World | Process: 4

test multiplication: 8Hello World | Process: 5

test multiplication: 10
```

As you can see from my output, the lines can get messed up if printing from different threads without serialization.